# How to get # of times in a row an item occurred in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to figure out the correct way to build this statement in SQL (oracle). What I have is a columns in a table that consists of "Date" and "Direction". In the direction column it either is a "North" or "South". I am trying to figure out how to output the # of times in a row before the row occurred (like a Win or Loss Streak) did "North" or "South appear". For example:

```
SELECT date, direction, ? As Streak FROM temptable order by date ASC;
```

**Sample dataset of 8 rows:**

1. 2022-01-01, North
2. 2022-01-02, North
3. 2022-01-03, North
4. 2022-01-04, North
5. 2022-01-05, South
6. 2022-01-06, South
7. 2022-01-07, South
8. 2022-01-08, North

The results would be:

**date, Direction, Streak**

1. 2022-01-01, North, 0;
2. 2022-01-02, North, 1;
3. 2022-01-03, North, 2;
4. 2022-01-04, North, 3;
5. 2022-01-05, South, 0;
6. 2022-01-06, South, 1;
7. 2022-01-07, South, 2;
8. 2022-01-08, North, 0;

Comment: For Oracle you might look at [`match_recognize`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/pattern-matching-in-oracle-database-12cr1). I doubt that will be available in MySQL or MariaDB though.

Comment: Please include sample data.

Comment: Given that the rows in a table have no intrinsic order, how are you ordering all the records that have the same date?

Comment: @NickW I updated the question to have different dates. Order by date asc

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, something else)? Please add the tag of your database to your question. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) to know why tagging is important. After adding the tag, vote to reopen your question. Without the tag, the question is too broad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with SQL Pattern Matching:

```
with rws as (
  select date'2022-01-01' dt, 'North' dir from dual union all
  select date'2022-01-02' dt, 'North' dir from dual union all
  select date'2022-01-03' dt, 'North' dir from dual union all
  select date'2022-01-04' dt, 'North' dir from dual union all
  select date'2022-01-05' dt, 'South' dir from dual union all
  select date'2022-01-06' dt, 'South' dir from dual union all
  select date'2022-01-07' dt, 'South' dir from dual union all
  select date'2022-01-08' dt, 'North' dir from dual
)
  select * from rws match_recognize (
    order by dt 
    measures 
      count(*) - 1 as streak
    all rows per match
    pattern ( init same* )
    define
      same as dir = init.dir
  );

DT              STREAK DIR  
----------- ---------- -----
01-JAN-2022          0 North
02-JAN-2022          1 North
03-JAN-2022          2 North
04-JAN-2022          3 North
05-JAN-2022          0 South
06-JAN-2022          1 South
07-JAN-2022          2 South
08-JAN-2022          0 North
```

The `pattern` is a regular expression using the variables listed in the `define` clause.

So it's searching for:

- Any row (`init`) - this is undefined so "always true"
- Followed by zero or more `same` variables
- These are rows where the value for `dir` matches that of the `init` "always true" row

The `measures` clause defines output columns. `count(*)` returns the running total of rows matched in the group so far.

The `all rows per match` clause is necessary because by default `match_recognize` returns one row per group. So you'd only get one row in the output for each streak.

Answer (score 2):

Not specifically Oracle but this is a standard approach using `row_number` to identify sequential groups, then to count *within* those groups:

```
with g as (
    select *, 
      Row_Number() over(order by date) 
       - Row_Number() over(partition by direction order by date) gn
    from t
)
select *, 
 Row_Number() over(partition by gn order by date) - 1 as Streak
from g
order by date;
```